# How to mock an uninitialized global variable?

Tags: python, unit-testing, global-variables, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have an uninitialzed global variable in my module that is properly initialized during application startup.  For typechecking I use the syntax `var: Type` without a value from python >= 3.6 so I do not have to complicate the typechecking for the default value (which would be `None`).

Now I want to unittest another function that uses this global variable but I get an error from `unittest.mock.patch`.  Here is a simplified version of what I am doing:

- File mod.py:

```py
global_var: bool
#global_var: bool = False
def init(val: bool) -> None:
    global global_var
    global_var = val
def do_stuff() -> str:
    return "a" if global_var else "b"
```

- File test.py:

```py
import unittest.mock, mod
class MockUninitializedGlobal(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_it(self):
        with unittest.mock.patch("mod.global_var", True):
            actual = mod.do_stuff()
        expected = "a"
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
```

- I run it with `python3 -m unittest test.py`.

The exception is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luc/soquestion/test.py", line 4, in test_it
    with mock.patch("mod.global_var", True):
  File "/nix/store/vs4vj1yzqj1bkcqkf3b6sxm6jfy1gb4j-python3-3.7.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 1323, in __enter__
    original, local = self.get_original()
  File "/nix/store/vs4vj1yzqj1bkcqkf3b6sxm6jfy1gb4j-python3-3.7.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 1297, in get_original
    "%s does not have the attribute %r" % (target, name)
AttributeError: <module 'mod' from '/home/luc/soquestion/mod.py'> does not have the attribute 'global_var'
```

If I comment line 1 and uncomment line 2 in mod.py the test passes.

Is there any way to make the test pass without definig a default value for the global variable in my application code?

---

<sub>Edit: As noted in the comments the actual variable is a parsed config file which I do not want to load during tests.  It is used in a command line application and therefore the variable is always set after command line parsing is done.  The real code is [here](https://github.com/scheibler/khard/blob/de7ba9b62395b727f31b37b01a23815fa44ca2d3/khard/khard.py#L29) and [here](https://github.com/scheibler/khard/blob/de7ba9b62395b727f31b37b01a23815fa44ca2d3/khard/khard.py#L1072-L1076).  In the actual test I am not trying to mock the global variable as a bool directly but some attribute on the config object.</sub>

Comment: run the `init` function first, no?

Comment: Mocking `mod.global_var` will never work if that name does not exist when you execute the `with`  statement. Since modules are also objects, you could "inject" that value by adding `mod.global_var = True` before and `del mod.global_var` after your `with` statement, but that's a hacky workaround. You should either run `init` beforehand as @gold_cy suggests or rethink your design - what do you gain from writing `global_var: bool` instead of `global_var: bool = False`?

Comment: In the real application the variable is called `config` and holds an instance of my parsed config file (which is represented by a custom class). I do not want to run `init()` and parse a config file in this unit test. I also do not want to set `config: Optional[Config] = None` in my module. Because for the real application and for typechacking I know that it will always be an instance of the `Config` class and never be used uninitialzed, and the type checking code would get more ugly if it had to handle the unnecessary `None` case.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use `Optional` (which I would prefer), you only have the possibility to initialize with some default-constructed light-weight config, or to add the variable directly to the module (the hack described by @jfaccioni).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods on the `unittest.TestCase` class to solve this.

With my edit above about it actually being a config object the code looks like this:

```py
class Config:
    def __init__(self, filename: str):
        "Load config file and set self.stuff"
        self.stuff = _code_to_parse(filename)
config: Config
def do_stuff() -> str:
    return "a" if config.stuff else "b"
```

And the test creates a mocked config object before the tests in order to mock some attribute on the config object during the test.  In the teardown I also delete the object again so that *nothing* will spill to the next test case.

The actual mocking of the attributes I need is then done in a `with` block in the actual test as it is (a) cleaner and (b) I can just mock what I need in contrast to mocking all attributes on the config object in the `setUp` method.

```py
import unittest, unittest.mock, mod
class MockUninitializedGlobal(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        mod.config = unittest.mock.Mock(spec=mod.Config)
    def tearDown(self):
        del mod.config
    def test_it(self):
        with unittest.mock.patch("mod.config.stuff", True):
            actual = mod.do_stuff()
        expected = "a"
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
```